# Check if a file is modified/unsaved

Tags: xcode

I found no option to see if a file is modified or unsaved in `Xcode`. I am using `Xcode` version `15`, but also in `Xcode` version `14` it is the same.

There is

- no indicator in the file navigator
- no indicator at the tab
- no indicator at the editor
- no menu option to list unsaved files
- even the Save menu item is always the same
  .

For Source Control there is the `M` at the file navigator for modified but not committed, but that is something different.

**Any idea how I could list/see if files are unsaved in Xcode?**  *Because Xcode crashes a lot in the last major versions in the big iOS projects I work on*

Comment: Files are basically never unsaved in Xcode, as it is constantly saving automatically. If in doubt, say Option Command S to save all; I also frequently say Command S while editing a file, because if we crash I might lost my most recent work.

Comment: @matt That is not true. Modified files are not saved automatically constantly. Even closing the editor does not save the file to disk. Closing the project will ask you if you want to save. Quitting Xcode, Committing and building will autosave. If Xcode crashes the changes are not saved in every case.